# Large Object Heap Fragmentation (LOH)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection, abp

I have a web application on .NET 4.6.1 with a very large memory consumption. 
I start to investigate with dotMemory to try to indentify the possibile issue and I see a lot of fragmentation
[image: LOH snapshot]

So now after read some thread on stackoverflow I undertand that string array generate this kind of issue, so I try to find a solution or a way to find where I my code this issue will be generated.

with dotMemory i see a lot of instance is releted to 
[image: Stack memory]

If I look some string internally I see a SQL query but I don't find a way to understand where it will be genereted.

[image]
inside the string I found a large query (more or less) 1500 rows.

Right now I don't find a way to reduce this kind of fragmentation.

-- Update

I add 2 snapshop with number of objets on memory dump for Gen0,1,2 and LOH. Looking into object I see a lots of query from EF (Sql Statement) with more than 1000 rows and large more the 85000 chars.

I found other issue in memory fragmentation raletad to minification process on MVC but is cover a small part of memory

[image: Memory and Objects]
[image: Memory dump]

Comment: Did you configure GC mode for your application, e.g. [`gcServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcserver-element)?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no I haven't configured it. I try.

Comment: How large is your large object heap, and other heaps?  It's impossible to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I more information on top